# Where to find an example of using cURL, PHP, and a pick list value to select another field?

Tags: picklist, php, curl

Can someone give an example, or a link to an example, of using PHP and cURL to select a column's value based on a pick list value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using SOQL instead of the REST API. The REST API needs a unique key to retrieve results whereas the SOQL commands are a bit more robust. I found this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B1xyIAC) helpful.